# Spring Cloud Data Flow ignores datasources configured by a spring batch app

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-dataflow

I'm setting up an instance of Spring Cloud Data Flow. I've run the following commands:

```
1. Run skipper server: java -jar spring-cloud-skipper-server-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar &
2. Run Dataflow server: java -jar spring-cloud-dataflow-server-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar \
    --spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://10.136.66.44:8080/springclouddataflow \
    --spring.datasource.username=springclouddataflow \
    --spring.datasource.password=123456 \
    --spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver \
    --server.port=80 &
```

In the second step, I'm using a postgres database, not the default h2.

I've developed a spring boot job using spring batch to be deployed in this plataform. The job uses two datasources: springclouddataflow for Spring and task Metadata and billrun for my business logic. When I run the app locally, it persists metadata in springclouddataflow and my business data in billrun, as expected.
The problem is when I try to execute de job inside the Spring Cloud Dataflow. The plataform ignores my configured business logic database and uses only the springclouddataflow database, which is supposed to store metadata only.

I've searched in the oficial [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/2.1.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#configuration-local-rdbms). It explains how to use a different database for metadata storage and how to configure several databases in an application. I've followed the instructions but without success.

application.properties

```
logging.level.org.springframework.cloud.task=debug
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
spring.batch.initialize-schema=always
spring.application.name=Bill Run
spring.datasource.jdbc-url=jdbc:postgresql://10.136.66.44:8080/springclouddataflow?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=springclouddataflow
spring.datasource.password=123456
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
app.datasource.jdbc-url=jdbc:postgresql://10.136.66.44:8080/billrun?useSSL=false
app.datasource.username=springclouddataflow
app.datasource.password=123456
app.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
```

DatasourceConfiguration

```
@Configuration
public class DatasourceConfiguration {
    @Bean(name = "appDatasource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "app.datasource")
    public DataSource sourceDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
    public DataSource springDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean
    public TaskConfigurer taskConfigurer() {
        return new DefaultTaskConfigurer(springDataSource());
    }
}
```

BillingConfiguration

```
@Configuration
@EnableTask
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BillingConfiguration {
    @Autowired
    public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Value("${usage.file.name:classpath:usageinfo.json}")
    private Resource usageResource;

    @Bean
    public Job job1(ItemReader<Usage> reader, ItemProcessor<Usage, Bill> itemProcessor, ItemWriter<Bill> writer) {
        Step step = stepBuilderFactory.get("BillProcessing").<Usage, Bill>chunk(1).reader(reader)
                .processor(itemProcessor).writer(writer).build();

        return jobBuilderFactory.get("BillJob").incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer()).start(step).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public JsonItemReader<Usage> jsonItemReader() {

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JacksonJsonObjectReader<Usage> jsonObjectReader = new JacksonJsonObjectReader<>(Usage.class);
        jsonObjectReader.setMapper(objectMapper);

        return new JsonItemReaderBuilder<Usage>().jsonObjectReader(jsonObjectReader).resource(usageResource)
                .name("UsageJsonItemReader").build();
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemWriter<Bill> jdbcBillWriter(@Qualifier("appDatasource") DataSource dataSource) {
        JdbcBatchItemWriter<Bill> writer = new JdbcBatchItemWriterBuilder<Bill>().beanMapped().dataSource(dataSource)
                .sql("INSERT INTO BILL_STATEMENTS (id, first_name, "
                        + "last_name, minutes, data_usage,bill_amount) VALUES "
                        + "(:id, :firstName, :lastName, :minutes, :dataUsage, " + ":billAmount)")
                .build();
        return writer;
    }

    @Bean
    ItemProcessor<Usage, Bill> billProcessor() {
        return new BillProcessor();
    }
}
```

I've tried passing the database properties as arguments to the task:

[image]

When I look at the datasource, there's only data persisted in springclouddataflow. How can I tell spring cloud data flow to use my application datasource (billrun)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are customizing the Spring Cloud Data Flow server to use the application's data sources which I think is not needed.

You can start your SCDF server as you posted above:

```
1. Run skipper server: java -jar spring-cloud-skipper-server-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar &
2. Run Dataflow server: java -jar spring-cloud-dataflow-server-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar \
    --spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://10.136.66.44:8080/springclouddataflow \
    --spring.datasource.username=springclouddataflow \
    --spring.datasource.password=123456 \
    --spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver \
    --server.port=80 &
```

and, have your Spring batch application passing its Data Source properties as Spring Boot properties instead of using a custom data source configuration as you did above.

You can find the Spring Batch application development guide using a similar approach [here](https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/batch-developer-guides/batch/spring-batch/)

Comment: I need this "customization" because I have to store my metadata in spring cloud database and my business data in application database. The approach suggested in the documentation configures a single database for metadata and business logic. How can I pass a second database for my spring batch task? I've tried passing as arguments to the task (spring boot configuration), but it doesn't work.

Comment: I've done another test passing the database properties as arguments and it worked! Thank's a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Just you try add dynamic data source in your application as bellow and then you Auto wire your dynamic Datasource where ever needed

```java
@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfig {

    @Bean(name = "testingDataSource")    
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "testing.datasource") 
    public DataSource testDataSource() { 
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build(); 
    }
    
    
    @Bean(name = "testingJdbcTemplate") 
    public JdbcTemplate testJdbcTemplate(@Qualifier("testingDataSource") DataSource dsMySQL) {
        return new JdbcTemplate(dsMySQL);
    }
    
}
```

testing:
datasource:
driverClassName: 'com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'
jdbc-url: 'jdbc:mysql://localhost/dbName'
username: 'uname'
password: 'passworcd'